# java spring request mapping

Tags: spring, request, mapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("success")
public class SuccessController {

private static Map<String, String>messages;

static {
    messages = new HashMap<>();
    messages.put("auth", "Authorisation");
}

@GetMapping("{act}")
public String success(@PathVariable String act, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("msg", messages.get(act));
    return "public/success";
}
```

The problem is after double request checks like this browser saves the first check parameter in http-form, and all following requests are save that substring. That crashes all following requests. How to avoid that and clear request address?

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is add "../" in the beginning of all links on the target page. That construction removes last "/*/" substring and replaces it with your link.
But this is not a perfect solution, so if you know better ways (desirable in java) - you are welcome)